# How can I avoid returning duplicate key value pairs when pushing to an array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, variables, javascript-objects

The pickWinners function will be passed an array of numbers representing ticket costs as its only argument. The index position represents the seat number.

I'm trying to return an array of objects. Each object should contain two keys. The first key is *seat* with a value of the odd index. The second key is *ticketCost* with a value of the ticket price at that index in the input array.

When I call the function with [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ] as arguments it returns:

[ { "seat": 5, "ticketCost": 7 }, { "seat": 5, "ticketCost": 7 }, { "seat": 5, "ticketCost": 7 } ],

but it should be:

[ { "seat": 1, "ticketCost": 3 }, { "seat": 3, "ticketCost": 5 }, { "seat": 5, "ticketCost": 7 } ]

What am I doing wrong?

See current code below...

```
function pickWinners(numbers) {

let objArr = [];

let obj = {
  seat: 0 ,
  ticketCost: 0
};

  for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {

    if (numbers[i] % 2 === 1) {
      obj.seat = i;
      obj.ticketCost = numbers[i];
      objArr.push(obj);
    };
  };
  return objArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct code:

```
function pickWinners(numbers) {

  let objArr = [];


  for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i += 2) {

    let obj = {
      seat: 0 ,
      ticketCost: 0
    };
    
    if (numbers[i] % 2 === 1) {
      obj.seat = i;
      obj.ticketCost = numbers[i];
      objArr.push(obj);
    };
  };
  return objArr;
}
```

You have to define obj inside the for loop